# What's the most memory-efficient way of operating matrices in Objective C? GLKit or CC

Tags: android, ios, iphone, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I am learning Objective C by porting and Android OpenGl app and I have run into this question.

In my android app I have a model matrix for every OpenGL object. Whenever I apply a transformation to that object, I recompute the model matrix by multiplying the traslation, scale and rotation matrices. I don't store these matrices, just the result because I need the app to be memory-efficient.

When porting this code to Obj-C I don't know what library to use to perform these operations. I thought of using GLKMatrix4, but every operation in that library seems to return a new matrix.

In Android this would be a problem, because I would be releasing a reference to a matrix every time and that would fire the GC really often.

I don't know if memory management in iOS works in such a way that I don't need to take care of that or if I should use another library that reuses the matrix I have (as I do in Android with Matrix.setIdentity(myMatrix)).

What would be the beast approach in this case?

Comment: A GLKMatrix4 is a plain old `struct`, not an object. It's not allocated dynamically; instead, it's returned by-value from the transformation functions. The only cost associated with this is the copying of 16 floating-point numbers, which is cheap. There's no retaining-releasing or any sort of garbage collection going on.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Coming from Java programming, I'm not used of thinking about non-objects. 
Still, even though it is memory efficient, it doesn't seem very efficient to move all those values around. Why isn't there a version of those functions that works by-reference and just updates the values (that would just require pushing to /pulling from the stack memory addresses instead of 16 floats each time)? Am I missing something?

Comment: it may not *seem* efficient, but it's probably the best you can get. Apple's performance engineers know what they are doing. If you have measured that this is a bottleneck, submit a bug report. Otherwise, just turn on compiler optimizations and don't worry about speed without having made benchmarks.

Comment: I think what you're doing is known as premature optimisation. You're not going to see any speed issues. Even if you computed one matrix per polygon, the drawing would still be your bottleneck (well, in that case it'd be handing all those state changes to OpenGL, but you know what I mean).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already said in the comments you should not worry about the memory with the `GLKMatrix4` as it is a C structure. If you have trouble imagining that think of it as an integer (`int`) in java.

As for the efficiency and creating new objects it is quite efficient this way because you can not do a matrix multiplication without creating another stack (another matrix buffer) on which to write the values so there is really no way to do the operation with only 2 values (at least I don't know any). The only optimization that could be done is that there was another argument in the function which would receive the target matrix pointer so you would lose a copy of 16 floats. But then again the copy of 16 floats is quite fast as already mentioned.

If you have doubts about using this matrix library it should be more then easy to create your own matrix library any way you please. For what is generally used in the `openGL` it should take someone `C` proficient less then an hour with testing included getting the equations from the web.

Comment: I asked about that because I saw [this](http://brenwill.com/docs/cocos3d/0.5-beta/api/interface_c_c3_g_l_matrix.html) this implementation of a library doing that and I was wondering whether it would make a difference in performance.

Comment: It might. It is strange you are trying to optimize on matrix operations as that is not very common. If for some reason you really have so many strange operations it is most likely you can optimize more on the operations/approaches you use then cutting down the copy calls. For instance creating a rotation matrix from angle can be extremely expensive. Another thing is you can define object position with base vectors with which you can directly create the matrix...

Comment: I paid attention to this issue because, since in Android matrices are dynamically assigned memory, losing their references deeply impacts performance. Seeing that this would not be a problem in this case I was just asking because it was counter-intuitive for me to pass the 16 floats back and forth instead of a pointer. I know there is little room for optimization there, if any, and it being a system library their creators must have taken all this into account, but since the enormously  popular Cocos3D library takes an approach similar to the one used in Android I thought it was worth asking.

Comment: You should understand that this GLK (GL Kit) is not a part of any standard, it is not used in anything internally and was created simply to ease the migration process from ES1 to ES2 for the developers. That means it was never meant as a "professional" toolset and in most likelihood you can find many better libraries doing the exact same thing. Though the guys who did this are quite good at what they do (the openGL team) and just looking at their code gives the impression of extreme performance. I guess you could try to compare-test other libraries but I would not bother.